# Reading a file from local file system after reading it from hadoop file system

Tags: scala, file, hadoop, filesystems, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to read a file from my local EMR file system. It is there as a file under the folder `/emr/myFile.csv`. However, I keep getting a `FileNotFoundException`. Here is the line of code that I use to read it:

```
val myObj: File = new File("/emr/myFile.csv")
```

I added a `file:////` prefix to the file path as well because I have seen that work for others, but that still did not work. So I also try to read directly from the hadoop file system where it is stored in the folder: `/emr/CNSMR_ACCNT_BAL/myFile.csv` because I thought it was maybe checking by default in hdfs. However, that also results in a `FileNotFoundException`. Here is the code for that:

```
val myObj: File = new File("/emr/CNSMR_ACCNT_BAL/myFile.csv")
```

How can I read this file into a File?

Answer (score 0):

#### For your 1<sup>st</sup> problem:

When you submit a hadoop job application master can get created on any of your worker node including master node (depending on your configuration).
If you are using EMR, your application master by default gets created on any of your worker node (CORE node) *but not on master*.

When you say `file:///emr/myFile.csv` this file exists on your local file system (I'm assuming that means on master node), your program will search for this file on that node where the application master is and its definitely not on your master node because for that you wouldn’t get any error.

---

#### 2<sup>nd</sup> problem:

When you try to access a file in HDFS using java `File.class`, it won’t be able to access that file.
You need to use hadoop FileSystem api (`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`) to interact with a HDFS file.

Also use HDFS file tag `hdfs://<namenode>:<port>/emr/CNSMR_ACCNT_BAL/myFile.csv`.
If your `core-site.xml` contains value of `fs.defaultFS` then you don’t need to put namenode and port info just simply `hdfs:///emr/CNSMR_ACCNT_BAL/myFile.csv`

---

So what's better option here while accessing file in hadoop cluster?
The answer depends upon your use case, but most cases putting it in HDFS it much better, because you don’t have to worry about where your application master is. Each and every node have access to the hdfs.

Hope that resolves your problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. So I tried to use copyToLocalFile method from the hadoop file system api using this code:     hadoopFileSystem.copyToLocalFile(hadoopFileSystem.globStatus(new Path("hdfs:///emr/CNS_ACCNT_BAL/part*.csv"))(0).getPath, new Path("file:///emr/myFile.csv"))
The process completes with no error, however, I cannot find that file in my local file system. I also tried with the destination path just being /emr/myFile.csv without the file:/// prefix, but still cannot find where it is. Any help with this?

Comment: How r u executing the program? If you are executing it as a hadoop job then the file `/emr/myFile.csv` will be in that node where your application master is.